# UIButton to show BackgroundImage, Image and Title

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, setbackground

I want to create a `UIButton` that uses its `setBackgroundImage`, `setImage`, and `setTitle` properties, but when I add `setTitle` in combination with `setImage` and `setBackgroundImage` the title doesn't appear.

I've tried the following.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"month_pct_general.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[button tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]]; 
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(45, 0, 0, 25)];
```

Comment: are you using button of custom type?

Comment: did u use this syntax [button setTitle;@"name" forState:UIControlstateNormal];

Comment: [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"month_pct_general.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];                               [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[button tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
                [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(45, 0, 0, 25)];

Comment: setImage cover the title，what can i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your title on button and on title your all image it there so add label on the image like this.

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,3,70,32)];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(compete) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UILabel *Label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 5, 60, 20)];
[Label setText:@"label"];

Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
Label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[myButton addSubview:Label];
```

your all image above the title only so your title is in background so use label on image view.

Comment: If this will be helpful for you inform us.

Comment: this answer works but is not the proper solution. you need to change the titleLabelEdgeInsets property of UIButton. the image is pushing the label off to the right. that's why you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making GUI using interface builder, then click on the label and go to Editor-> Arrange -> Send to Front.